# Prolog, find value with smallest difference to reference value in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I need your help with Prolog, I hope my explanation is not too difficult.

The general problem is: i have a list with several feature structures (which are actually feature:value lists in Prolog) with a value "time:xyz" among other values. I have a reference feature structure with a reference time. Now I need the feature structure with the closest time value to my reference time.

My plan is to go through the the list and compare each entry with the current smallest difference to the reference time.
The problem is that the variable `MinFSR` which is the current minimum has no value the first time `minimum(...)` is called. So I get an error.
How can I check whether `MinFSR`has already a value? I want to check this and if it hasn't a value then I want to call `list_min` with the `H` as new `MinFSR`.

```
list_min([], ReferenceFSR, MinFSR). %if list is empty stop
list_min([H|T], ReferenceFSR, MinFSR) :-
   minimum(H, MinFSR, ReferenceFSR, Min1),
   list_min(T, ReferenceFSR, Min1).


minimum(FSR1, FSR2, ReferenceFSR, MinFSR):-
   % reads out and compares the time of FSR1 and FSR2 to the referenceFSR 
   % and MinFSR is the FSR1 or FSR2 depending on which has the smaller
   % difference
```

I hope you can understand my problem although I wrote it very complicated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're close, but your predicate needs to be reworked a little. The recursive case should look at the two head elements of the list since you are already given a predicate, `minimum/4`, which yields the desired choice from comparing a pair of values.

```
list_min([X], _, X).       % X is min for single list, [X]
list_min([X,Y|T], ReferenceFSR, MinFSR) :-
    minimum(X, Y, ReferenceFSR, Min),
    list_min([Min|T], ReferenceFSR, MinFSR).
```